# positioning a fixed div under another div for scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I'm trying to make a *vertical share buttons* for a blog post.

The vertical container should has a fixed position while the reader is scrolling, after setting `top: 15px;` to the vertical container, it covers the title div, which is my problem. I want it to be *fixed* but under the title.

*knowing that the height of the title is **unknown.***

So what solutions are available?

```css
html{
    margin:0 49px;
}

.panel{
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
}
.title{
       background-color: cyan; 
    height:60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:15px;
}
.content{
    padding:15px 60px 15px 15px;
}
.vertical-container{    
    position: fixed;
 right: 45px;
 top:15px;
 min-height: 200px;
 background-color: #3B5998;
 width: 60px;
}
.vertical-container:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 5px;
    right: 0px;
    border-color: #23355B transparent transparent #23355B;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="title"> unknown title height </div>
    <div class="content">
        Performed suspicion in certainty so frankness by attention pretended. Newspaper or in tolerably education enjoyment. Extremity excellent certainty discourse sincerity no he so resembled. Joy house worse arise total boy but. Elderly up chicken do at feeling is. Like seen drew no make fond at on rent. Behaviour extremely her explained situation yet september gentleman are who. Is thought or pointed hearing he. 
 Rendered her for put improved concerns his. Ladies bed wisdom theirs mrs men months set. Everything so dispatched as it increasing pianoforte. Hearing now saw perhaps minutes herself his. Of instantly excellent therefore difficult he northward. Joy green but least marry rapid quiet but. Way devonshire introduced expression saw travelling affronting. Her and effects affixed pretend account ten natural. Need eat week even yet that. Incommode delighted he resolving sportsmen do in listening. 

    </div>
<div class="vertical-container"></div>
</div>
```

If you prefer [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/markor91/h5t7pgfb/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using jQuery, here is a vanilla javascript solution. It's getting the title height and then making that the top position of the vertical container.

```
<script>
    // get title element
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0],
        // get vertical container element
        container = document.getElementsByClassName('vertical-container')[0],
        // get height of title
        elHeight = el.offsetHeight;
    // set vertical container height
    container.style.top = elHeight + 'px';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without javascript, you can postion your container 100% (of the height of the title) from the top of your title.
To achieve that, the container div has to be either inside the title div or a title-container of the same (title) height.

Css:

```
.title{
//  height:60px; unknown...
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:15px;
}

.title-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.vertical-container{    
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;

    right: 45px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color:   #3B5998;
    width:  60px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="panel">

  <div class="title container">
    <div class="title"> unknown title height </div>
    <div class="vertical-container">
      <div>Like!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Performed suspicion...
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the title (or its container) is fixed to the top with height x...

> be careful of margins, as they are not included in the height-calculation of this element.
>   use an invisible container fixed to the top with margin 0 and assign a margin to the title if you like

...and the vertical container is placed 100% (of x) beneath, absolute to its fixed parent.